# The bulb like symbol in visual studio (vs) code what cause this to happen?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

The bulb, I can't seem to explain what is causing this to happen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkAwg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are code actions: suggestions of fixes provided by VS Code's AI. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action